# AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver is draining battery when sleeping in macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, battery, sleep-wake, ventura

I have a new MacBook Pro M1 Max running Ventura 13.2.1 with just 34 battery cycles but already 92% max capacity.

Using `log show --last boot --style syslog | fgrep "Wake reason"`  I was able to see that my Mac is waking up every 10-15 min during the night (and during the day) because of the same reason, which is making me believe this is the root of all my problems :

```
2023-03-07 22:44:56.603109-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-07 23:01:04.536040-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-07 23:18:42.538172-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-07 23:34:36.508399-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-07 23:50:05.504202-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 00:08:07.542482-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 00:25:38.515148-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 00:42:24.533949-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 00:57:50.521994-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 01:15:53.599009-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 01:33:54.532834-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 01:49:23.538349-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 02:06:28.540961-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 02:24:30.579498-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 02:40:25.599216-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2023-03-08 02:57:34.586014-0300  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
```

I tried `sudo pmset -a tcpkeepalive 0` and turning off my Bluetooth (manually and with Bluesnooze), but the battery is still getting drained (15%-20%) overnight.

Can someone tell me what this process is and how I can kill it? To see if it fixes my issue?

Comment: Did you solve? I'm facing the same issue with an M2.

Comment: I also have this problem on all of my macs. It seems like intentional thing from Apple to kill battery as fast as they can. Even Apple support is saying that current macos is designed to prevent macs from expected sleep.

Comment: @Rimvydas Just as a data point, I don't have this on my M1 Pro MBP.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should running Apple Diagnostics to test your Mac firstly.

I also have same problem, and I running this. It showed maybe there are hardware problems on my trackpad, Error code is NDR007, and recommended me to Apple support or Apple official stores.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/344802)